# Why section background is not changing in elementor plugin of wordpress on live site?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

When my website was in development stage(i.e. when it's on localhost), I was easily able to change section background and effects used to reflect immediately. But when I made my site live on Windows Server 2012 and tried to update section backgrounds, background is not updating. Whenever I add new image to server, it's not displaying in section background. But when I try old uploaded images, all those images display.

I tried following possible solutions:

1. I changed absolute path's of images to relative path, but not worked,
2. I cleared wordpress' cache, it also not worked,
3. I cleared browser cache, it also not worked,
4. I changed "CSS Print Method option" to "Internal Embedding" from "External CSS" in elementor's settings option, it also not worked,
5. I'm not using another page builder
6. I tried templates that also not worked.

I checked this elementor's link also - [My changes do not appear online, what can I do?](https://docs.elementor.com/article/204-my-changes-do-not-appear-online)

But above document didn't work for me. Is there anyone faced this issue and have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 6):

For the second time i struggled with this issue for hours only to find the quick fix:

Elementor > Settings > Advanced > CSS Print Method > Internal Embedding

Comment: Man this was a life saver

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs just because of "User Permissions". I used Microsoft Windows Server 2012, So I followed following steps:

1. Go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools
2. Search for Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager and double click on it
3. Then go to sites
4. Select your live site -> Right click on it -> Edit permisions
5. Go to Security tab
6. Click on edit -> Click on "Add..." button for adding new user.
7. Type Every -> click on Check Names -> Click on Ok
8. Now you can see "Permissions for Everyone" options below Add and Remove buttons.
9. Check full control check box and click on apply
10. And finally click on Ok.

Now elementor can read images. When you'll update image, you need to stay calm and wait to update. It'll take time to change.

Don't make Image Size option full, it'll take too much time to update. Instead of that use 1024x1024. It'll update fast and you can see change immediately.

Just don't forget to remove that user after complete updation of live site. It's bad practice to have full access to live site.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of your answers, but with no effect.

Style > Background and then select HOVER (Instead of NORMAL) finally did the trick!

Comment: There are many possibilities and many ways of solving the problem. Things which worked for me I had already put it in my answer. Things which worked for me which are suggested by other people are also upvoted. May be for your code that solution did not work. It depends on your code and the thing which you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I couldn't get images or background colors to show up on my background.  I found that the background overlay was set to white with an opacity of 100%.  Once I set it to 0% opacity everything worked.  I don't remember setting any overlay so it was probably on by default.