# Background Images Not Loading In Elementor

Tags: elementor

My website is not loading the background images on live version - it just shows the text and a grey screen.

I built the site using Elementor.

[Here](https://wwlandscaping.com/services/garden-decking/) are the pages

(all service pages).

I compressed all images to about 100K so they shouldn't be too big to load. The one one the homepage is 99K and it loads.

Thanks

Comment: I am deleting and reuploading the images now - thanks! But the file path had the new url - I don't understand. Is image url and file path the same thing? Where can you change them?

Comment: Generally whenever I develop sites using wordpress, I export the site using a plugin like wp migration, then install fresh copy of wp on the live server, install plugin wp migration on live server, then import the site. Saves alot of headache about links not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954052/why-section-background-is-not-changing-in-elementor-plugin-of-wordpress-on-live/59667997#59667997

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954052/why-section-background-is-not-changing-in-elementor-plugin-of-wordpress-on-live/59667997#59667997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images are still referencing localhost. for example `http://localhost/woodworks/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/services-decking.jpeg`. I advise you to export your site using something like all in one [wp migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/), so that it fixes the links or find a way of fixing these image links.

Comment: when i tried to show on image view , its appear and show , but for section element bacgkround it doesnt show . so the path is correctly .

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the page you linked the path to the background image you are trying to have show up has this path: http://localhost/woodworks/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/services-decking.jpeg

**You can solve it**

Step 1 - Elementor -> Tools -> Replace URL -> `http://localhost/` -> `https://wwlandscaping.com` -> **Replace URL**

Step 2 - Elementor -> Tools -> General -> Regenerate CSS -> **Regenerate Files** & Sync Library -> **Sync Library**

Comment: Thank you so much,  that's the exact accurate solution for elementor .

Comment: My problem with this procedure is all other images work fine, but background images are not! Background images do not work on public site, but they show up when I edit the pages...

Answer (score 3):

I had similar challenges getting Elementor background images to load on devices in local environments using Local WP with live link.

Here's how I solved for it. The [Elementor Migration Guide](https://docs.elementor.com/article/467-site-migration) was super helpful.

From the elementor migration guide:

> Background images are saved in a CSS file which has an absolute URL.
>   To avoid migrating issues with the background images without having to
>   write a script, you can define the CSS Print Method to be inline
>   instead of using external files, if you want. This can be done by
>   going to Elementor > Settings > Advanced > CSS Print Method > Internal
>   Embedding> CSS print method: inline, on your WP dashboard.

**Here's what got elementor background images working on local devices for me. I'm using Local WP with live links for device testing:**

1. In your local environment set the local Elementor css print method
   to "internal embedding" (Elementor > Settings > Advance)
2. Conduct a url rewrite (old environment URL to new environment URL)
3. Regenerate Elementor files (Elementor > Tools > General)

After I did this, in my local environment, my background images showed up in local devices. I then did a push to staging and prod (database included) to see if the background images were still visible and they were. Everything worked.

For production - Elementor cites performance enhancements when having Elementor's css print method set to "external".

**If you want to do this on prod, after you're done with your device testing, follow these steps:**

1. In your prod environment set the local Elementor css print method to "external file" (Elementor > Settings > Advance)
2. Conduct a url rewrite (old environment URL to new environment URL)
3. Regenerate Elementor files (Elementor > Tools > General)

I think this should solve the Elementor background image conundrum when developing sites locally and on devices. Please let me know if I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the page you linked the path to the background image you are trying to have show up has this path: `http://localhost/woodworks/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/services-decking.jpeg` You can see you are still referencing your `localhost` which is your internal webserver and not the one you are using now. If you remove the localhost domain it should work correct provided the image is in the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Elementor -> Tools -> Replace URL -> http://localhost/ -> https://wwlandscaping.com -> Replace URL

Step 2 - Elementor -> Tools -> General -> Regenerate CSS -> Regenerate Files & Sync Library -> Sync Library

Step 3 - go to page and click edit page from elementor. Select image background and remove image.

step 4 - click update.

step 5 - upload image again and click update.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace your URLs. Log in to your Wordpress account on whichever server it is hosted.

On your Dashboard screen, navigate to Elementor -> Tools. In General tab, regenerate CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround because the tools from Elementor didn't helped: connect via FTP to your website.

Go to the following folder: `/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css`

download them and search and replace the old background URLs

For me I had some CSS in another folder: `/wp-content/uploads/ao_ccss`

I changed the background URLs there and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has this problem (on laptop) and is at the end of there wits.... check the background on android.....if the background shows then the issue is with breakpoints. For some reason settings for laptop/pc were not set. Only mobile/tablet were preset for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6rWr.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me find the issue I was having with background images not showing but in my case it was a permissions issue.  Make sure that the `/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css` folder is writeable by the webserver.